# 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll - DateTime

Tags: vb.net, datetime, error-handling

Also having the following troubleshooting tips appear...
"When converting a String to DateTime, parse the String to take the data before putting each variable into the DateTime object"

I can't figure out why my programme is trying to convert this to DateTime?
My access database (connected) is strictly autoNumbers, Numbers & Short Text.

```
Dim objConnection As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source= InfoSystem.accdb")
Dim objAdminDA As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("Select *from tblStudents", objConnection)
Dim objAdminCB As New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(objAdminDA)
Dim objDataSet As New DataSet()

Private Sub frmAdmin_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    'Clears DataSet of any existing data
    objDataSet.Clear()
    'Fills schema - adds table structure information to DataSet
    objAdminDA.FillSchema(objDataSet, SchemaType.Source, "tblStudents")
    'Fills DataSet with info from the DataAdapter
    objAdminDA.Fill(objDataSet, "tblStudents")
    'Fill the DataSet with info from the Admin table
    objAdminDA.FillSchema(objDataSet, SchemaType.Source, "tblStudents")
    objAdminDA.Fill(objDataSet, "tblStudents")

    Dim objRow As DataRow
    objRow = objDataSet.Tables("tblStudents").Rows.Find("StudentNo")

    txtAdminID2.Text = objRow.Item("StudentName")
    txtAdminName2.Text = objRow.Item("AdminName")
    txtDept2.Text = objRow.Item("Department")
    txtTitle2.Text = objRow.Item("Title")
```

The following code eradicated the problem on a previous form, but can't seem to manipulate it here. (TextBox instead of ComboBox). First time using Databases with VB.net.

```
Dim objRow As DataRow
    objRow = objDataSet.Tables("tblAdmins").Rows.Find(cboxAdminID.SelectedItem.ToString)
    txtAdminName.Text = objRow.Item("AdminName")
    txtDept.Text = objRow.Item("Department")
    txtTitle.Text = objRow.Item("Title")
```

Comment: I don't have any Dates in my database, or in my project for that matter!

Comment: forgive me, are you just wanting it to automatically add the time of day to a grid each time the user opens the program/goes to the new line of the table?

Answer (score 0):

I would change your code, because you are filling the dataset twice:

```
Dim objConnection As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source= InfoSystem.accdb")
Dim objAdminDA As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from tblStudents", objConnection)
Dim objAdminCB As New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(objAdminDA)
Dim objDataSet As New DataSet()

Private Sub frmAdmin_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

'Clears DataSet of any existing data
objDataSet.Clear()
'Fills DataSet with info from the DataAdapter
objAdminDA.Fill(objDataSet, "tblStudents")

' Get the row with the matching StudentNo
Dim objRow As DataRow
objRow = objDataSet.Tables("tblStudents").Rows.Find("StudentNo")

If objRow.count = 1 Then
    txtAdminID2.Text = objRow.Item("StudentName").ToString
    txtAdminName2.Text = objRow.Item("AdminName").ToString
    txtDept2.Text = objRow.Item("Department").ToString
    txtTitle2.Text = objRow.Item("Title").ToString
End-if
```

Comment: Also you are missing a space before the * in your query.